# write a skype plugin for this requirements

Tags: skype, video-conferencing

I'm starting some research on skype programming. Is there one technologie for skype plugins or are there multiple frameworks or apis?
I'd like to make a plugin where user from my database can communicate with each other (video, audio, chat) over skype without seeing each others' real skype id's - is it possible? (I guess yes, I tried skycandy a couple years ago and it was actually the same)
any hints for realization?
primary platform would be windows, but maybe android/ios as well (are mobile versions plugin enabled?)
Is skype a good choice for the requirements or is there a better solution for a small project without budget?

Answer (score 3):

Skype offers an API for its Desktop clients, Desktop API and an SDK for you build your own client.

The Desktop API is in maintenance mode and doesn't support newer features in the client and has a number of known bugs.

SkypeKit is fully supported but doesn't currently support Multi Part Video, at the time of writing.

Neither of these technologies can be used on mobile devices, in the case of SkypeKit its specifically prohibited in the licence terms, and you may never obscure the sending or receiving parties Skype name as this is prohibited.

For additional info please see http://developer.Skype.com

Allen Smith
Community Manager
Skype Developer