# Writing a Skype addon/plugin (2016)?

Tags: api, skype

I would like to develop a plugin/addon for Skype (desktop client), with the following requirements:

- When the plugin/addon is installed, one gets a new menu option in Skype
- Choosing this option shows a new window with text boxes, labels, checkboxes which allow setup
- based on the setup, a graphical overlay is created, and laid over the Skype video (being sent from host machine over the Internet to the recipients)

Ultimately, the effect of the video overlay would be similar to what is advertised here: http://blogs.skype.com/2015/10/28/add-fun-filters-to-your-skype-video-messages-in-the-latest-skype-for-android-iphone-and-ipad/

Note that I do not want to develop a third party application that uses Skype - I'd want to develop a plugin/addon, which will "live" inside the Skype application.

I have found some resources, but I am having difficulties seeing what is still supported:

- [Implementation of Skype API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259923/implementation-of-skype-api) (2009) has an example of a third party app using a Skype API via Skype4COM wrapper; but:
- https://aragonresearch.com/microsoft-kills-skype-desktop-apis-leaves-developers-scrambling/ (2013) - Skype4COM is no longer supported
- [write a skype plugin for this requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613159/write-a-skype-plugin-for-this-requirements) (2012) - unclear which, if any, of the approaches noted there, is applicable to my requirements above
- https://www.skype.com/en/developer/ - it offers me "Build a bot" (not sure if applicable to my task), Skype buttons and Skype URIs (definitely not applicable to my task), Skype for Business Skype Web SDK (it's for web applications, so probably not applicable).

So, is there an API that would allow me to do this, and if so, where can I find more resources to research it?

If there isn't such an API, is there an API that I could use to develop a third-party standalone application, that would integrate with Skype so as to achieve the goals of my task (custom video overlay set from a GUI)?

Comment: So let me get this straight... You want us to recommend you an API?

Comment: Thanks @Laurel - indeed, I do; it's just that there is so much confusing information out there, that I'm not sure if there is a Skype API (for programming something like this) supported from Skype/Microsoft anymore (even though it clearly was in the past). If nothing like this is supported anymore from Skype/Microsoft, I would accept a qualified (i.e. supported with a link/official statement) "No" answer... If I could find a straight forward statement online, I would definitely not ask here.

Comment: @sdbbs finally did you find this api? I am interested to do the same. I found Skype Developer Platform (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skypedeveloperplatform) but only for windows, I am looking for to MacOs. I know that there is a way, actually exist a Call Recorder plugin (http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/)